# Decide if the function is improperly integrable on I

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

Find its value

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2}, I = [-1,1]$$

obviously this is undefined at $$x=0$$

$$\int_{-1}^0 \frac{1}{x^2} + \int_0^1 \frac{1}{x^2}$$

set $0 = b$

for the first integral:

$$\int_{-1}^b \frac{1}{x^2} = \lim_{b\to0^-} \frac{-1}{x} \Big\vert_{b}^{-1} =$$ undefined $-(-1)$

for the second integral: -1-undefined. The back of the book says its just undefined

$$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x^2}=\lim_{b\to 0^+} \frac{-1}{x} \Big\vert_b^1$$

Comment: See:  https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2098557/693161

Comment: thats way too long of a proof for this class its an introduction to real analysis, in the past when I have used longer and more complicated proofs from answers I get marked off significantly

Comment: Perhaps if that was mentioned, we would've just known to say "the integral diverges".

Comment: 1. In your evaluation of the first integral, you've incorrectly switched the lower and upper limit of integration.
2. Once you've shown one of the two diverges, it follows that the entire integral diverges. No need to check the other integral.

Comment: Is your question why is it when you find "undefined $\ -(-1)$" and "$-1 -\ $ undefined", the book just says "undefined"? That is because "undefined" is not a value. You cannot add to it or subtract from it. It just means that there is no number the limit converges to. "undefined $\ -(-1)$" and "$-1 -\ $ undefined" are expressions without any meaning. That is, they are "undefined".